# How to observe on LiveData in ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

On `PostsByLabelViewModel` it have `MutableLiveData<String> token` this token is changed every scrolling of recyclerView, I need to observe on it in the `PostsByLabelViewModel` not from UI, because I tried to change it in `recyclerView.addOnScrollListener` and the app is freezing and hanged. Here's the code:

```
public class PostsByLabelViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public static final String TAG = "PostsByLabelViewModel";

    public MutableLiveData<PostList> postListMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> finalURL = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> token = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void getPostListByLabel() {

        Log.e(TAG, finalURL.getValue());

       PostsByLabelClient.getINSTANCE().getPostListByLabel(finalURL.getValue()).enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostList> call, Response<PostList> response) {
                PostList list = response.body();

                if (list.getItems() != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, list.getNextPageToken());
                    token.setValue(list.getNextPageToken());
                    postListMutableLiveData.setValue(list);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostList> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I see there's an `observe` method on the `ViewModel` and I tried to use it like this

```
token.observe(PostsByLabelViewModel.this, new Observer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(String s) {
                        token.setValue(s);
                    }
                });
```

but I got runtime error

```
error: incompatible types: PostsByLabelViewModel cannot be converted to LifecycleOwner
                token.observe(PostsByLabelViewModel.this, new Observer<String>() {
```

So how can I observe on the token on every change?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to observe on it in the `PostsByLabelViewModel` not from UI.

You might use [observeForever](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#observeforever). Just don't forget to call [removeObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#removeObserver(androidx.lifecycle.Observer)) when it is no longer needed.

> ...the app is freezing and hanged.

You're calling `PostsByLabelClient.getINSTANCE().getPostListByLabel(finalURL.getValue()).enqueue` on the main thread. Move it to a background thread.